# Facing Issue in Comparing two HashMap in synchronized method/function

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap

```
static protected HashMap<String, String> secMapMulti = new HashMap<String, String>();
static protected HashMap<String, String> baMapMulti = new HashMap<String, String>();
static protected HashMap<String,PrintWriter> writeAndClientId = new HashMap<String,PrintWriter>();
static String client_id = "";
static PrintWriter pw_eq=null;
static String[] split_str_data;
static int data_length;

public static synchronized void serveAllWriters(String data) {
    split_str_data = data.split(",");
    data_length = data.indexOf('|');


    for (Map.Entry<String, PrintWriter> entry : writeAndClientId.entrySet()) {
        pw_eq = entry.getValue();
        client_id = entry.getKey();

        if (baMapMulti.containsKey(nse_eq_client_id + ":" + split_str_data[0])) {
            pw_eq.println(data);
        } else {
            if (secMapMulti.containsKey(client_id + "-" + split_str_data[0])) {
                data = data.substring(0, data_length + 1);
                pw_eq.println(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes both the HashMap gets compared and sometimes only the first value of hashmap gets compared, something weird is happening two Hashmap contains the values which needs to be compared on the basis of particular condition.

Answer (score 0):

Problem description not very clear? You have `if else` branching statements if one condition is true it wont look in to the code in else block. Is that what your problem is?

Theres no way both maps would get compared at the same time as you are using `if-else`

Answer (score 0):

Hey your suggests only that. You are either printing the data if the key is baMapMulti or if the key is in secMapMulti. The "data" will be printed in either one of the key the lookups or never get printed at all if the key is not found in both the maps. But data never gets printed   from both the hashmap look ups.  But I am not sure if I have answered question, because question is not really clear. Please edit the question for correct answers. One humble opinion  is, name your maps in little more clear way (ba and sec don't mean anything to me).Cheers.